# Navigating Avatar Around Game Map Issues: Avatar Hidden Inside Tiles & Click Animation

Tags: unity-game-engine, navigation, avatar, navmesh

I am currently working on a tower defense game in Unity (2018.4). I am very new to this software and C#. Right now I have an avatar that moves around my game screen via a NavMesh plane.

The orange box in my pic below shows where the transparent plane is sitting. My game map (brown and green) consists of textured tiles.

[image]

[image]

My avatar is the gray thing you see on the screen. I use NavMeshAgent and a couple of scripts to move my avatar around based on where my mouse clicks on the game map.

Below is a link to a video of my avatar moving.

https://forum.unity.com/threads/navigating-avatar-around-game-map-issues-avatar-hidden-inside-tiles-click-animation.759737/

I'm trying to get help for the following two issues.

1) when I move my avatar to a more elevated place (i.e. higher stack of tiles) he disappears inside the tile (see gif). I want the avatar to either be standing on top of the tile or on a lower level next to it.

2) when I click on a tile in the game map to direct my avatar to move there, I want some indication or animation of where I clicked. (i.e. an arrow or circle on the spot of my mouse click).

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

On #1:

Make sure your tile GameObjects have colliders. Set the layer of the avatar to "Ignore Raycast". Then call `Physics.RayCast` from a point at the same x and z coordinates as your avatar, but at a Y coordinate above the highest point a tile might reach. Set a mask on the call so that GameObjects on "Ignore Raycast" layer won't generate a hit. `RayCast` will return a coordinate from which you can retrieve a `Y` value and use it for your avatar's positioning about the tile. More info about calling `Raycast` can be found here - https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html .

On #2:

I don't think you shouldn't ask two questions, so I've intentionally not answered the second one. I recommend editing your question to remove question #2. And just ask a separate question on Stack Overflow. It's a better way to structure the information so that other people besides you can learn from answers given to your questions. I say this in a friendly way.

Comment: thank you Erik ... I will remove question #2 into a new question.